# Draw RenderTexture on screen in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

please, what wrong is there? It is fine in editor, but on Galaxy S6 I have only black screen.

```
RenderTexture texture;

void Start () {
    texture = new RenderTexture (800, 480, 24);
    RenderTexture.active = texture;
}

void Update () {
}

void OnPreRender(){
    Camera.main.targetTexture = texture;
}

void OnPostRender() {
    Camera.main.targetTexture = null;
    Graphics.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), texture);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render Texture Black on Android Only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196619/render-texture-black-on-android-only)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Unity. You can find more details at:

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rendertexture-not-working-on-ios-and-android-unity-4-2-0f4.192561/

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/render-texture-not-working-on-device-unity-5-2-1f1.358483/

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/render-texture-works-in-editor-but-not-on-devices-after-upgrade-to-unity-5.362397/

and a few others where the moderators and staff claim it is fixed in a future release or (with a touch of unnecessary arrogance) that the issue is the user and a bug never existed at all.

***BUT***

This is going to sound silly, but add an ImageEffect to the main camera. I have made a dummy effect that is attached to my main camera and without any logical explanation, it fixes RenderTexture on mobile.

DummyEffect.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
[AddComponentMenu("Image Effects/Dummy Effect")]
public class DummyEffect : ImageEffectBase {

    // Called by camera to apply image effect
    void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination) {
        Graphics.Blit (source, destination, material);
    }
}
```

DummyEffect.shader:

```
Shader "Hidden/Dummy Effect" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", RECT) = "white" {}
}

SubShader {
    Pass {
        ZTest Always Cull Off ZWrite Off
        Fog { Mode off }

CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert_img
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
#include "UnityCG.cginc"

uniform sampler2D _MainTex;

float4 frag (v2f_img i) : COLOR {
    return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
}
ENDCG

    }
}

Fallback off

}
```

Comment: You can still assign a previously made RenderTexture in place of the two creation lines. I created a new one to eliminate the possibility that the RenderTexture itself was an issue.

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? I have the same issue

Comment: You replied to it.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use MAIN camera for this. Just add additional one, that will render texture.