# Render Texture Black on Android Only

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rendering

I want to draw view of camera in texture and show texture in canvas, if camera not moving. I run it for android then I got black texuture, but for WebPlayer is Good!

```
public RawImage rawImage;

private void Start()
{
   texture = new RenderTexture(camera.pixelWidth, camera.pixelHeight, 32, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
    texture.antiAliasing = 8;
    texture.Create();
}

public void ShowTexture()
{
   camera.targetTexture = texture;
   RenderTexture.active = texture2;
   if (!RenderTexture.active.IsCreated())
      RenderTexture.active.Create();

   camera.Render();

   var texture2d = new Texture2D(camera.targetTexture.width, camera.targetTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, true, true);
   texture2d.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, camera.pixelWidth, camera.pixelHeight), 0, 0);
   texture2d.Apply(false);

   RenderTexture.active = null;
   camera.targetTexture = null;

  rawImage.texture = texture2d;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it's because you copy-pasted this code from somewhere on the internet. The Update() (and all other monobehaviour) functions are ordered randomly when application compiles, the order may be different on other platforms. You may need to order them explicitly using the **Unity Execution Order**. In a word - make sure camera.targetTexture is not null when main camera renders.
**Other tips:** you can not have 32 bit texture [Source](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture-ctor.html). Also, try putting antialiasing a bit low, 8 is too much for any phone, it's very demanding.

Comment: @NikaKasradze While it is common on SO for people to immediately assume code was pasted without any knowledge of it, this is the result of a bug in Unity. An extremely well-known bug in Unity. RenderTexture has had issues since 4.X that persist into current builds today.

Comment: @LoungeKatt my bad, I don't know what hit me, editing my comment, thanks, EDIT: I can not edit my previous commet lol, it's too old ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I admit it was a bit rude of me for which I apologize

Answer (score 2):

figure this might help someone...

Replicated same issue by accident... working both on iOS and Droid.
Then disabled camera clear, and hey presto... works on iOS but black on Android.
changed camera clear back to Z-depth only...  and both iOS and Droid work again.

So try changing your camera clear settings.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working with unity ver 2019.2.0f1.
For unknown reasons the initial camera I had imported from an earlier version was showing a black render texture and the new one was working perfectly.
I seem to have found a solution, something on the camera itself seems to be the issue. Delete camera, re-create and Color Format on the render texture rgba8_unorm with depth buffer at 24
Now both show up properly on android.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Unity. You can find more details at:

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rendertexture-not-working-on-ios-and-android-unity-4-2-0f4.192561/

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/render-texture-not-working-on-device-unity-5-2-1f1.358483/

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/render-texture-works-in-editor-but-not-on-devices-after-upgrade-to-unity-5.362397/

and a few others where the moderators and staff claim it is fixed in a future release or (with a touch of unnecessary arrogance) that the issue is the user and a bug never existed at all.

***BUT***

This is going to sound silly, but add an ImageEffect to the main camera. I have made a dummy effect that is attached to my main camera and without any logical explanation, it fixes RenderTexture on mobile.

DummyEffect.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
[AddComponentMenu("Image Effects/Dummy Effect")]
public class DummyEffect : ImageEffectBase {

    // Called by camera to apply image effect
    void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination) {
        Graphics.Blit (source, destination, material);
    }
}
```

DummyEffect.shader:

```
Shader "Hidden/Dummy Effect" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", RECT) = "white" {}
}

SubShader {
    Pass {
        ZTest Always Cull Off ZWrite Off
        Fog { Mode off }

CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert_img
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
#include "UnityCG.cginc"

uniform sampler2D _MainTex;

float4 frag (v2f_img i) : COLOR {
    return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
}
ENDCG

    }
}

Fallback off

}
```